# Manual Installation of php extension (copy from one server to another)

Tags: php, linux

I am trying to use the following imagick code in my backup server:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$image = new Imagick('image.jpg');

$image->thumbnailImage(100, 0);

echo $image;

?>
```

However, this is a backup server which is not having the imagick.so installed. Our office has one primary server (same OS version, same linux distribution) with the imagick.so. Can I manually copy the imagickso to the backup server and make it working ?

Comment: Normally you can just install it via the package management system, then it will make sure all dependencies, config etc is created as well. I don't really know why you would want to do it manually

Comment: Yes, but the server is a very old one (Fedora 1x) and we have tried to download and install the package which is suitable for this version but it is no longer available.

Comment: If your o/s is so old that they took away the package repository then it means you are a long time past the time for an upgrade. Unless you have a very special reason (e.g. hardware which only works with that exact o/s version) then not upgrading leaves you at risk of security issues and of course you are falling behind with features and updates. I'd guess your version of PHP is out of support too. If the server is used by anyone more than just you it's pretty irresponsible not to keep it up to date and secure

Comment: Yes, I agree with @ADyson. If possible please upgrade your system to a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should build the PHP extension in your server thru package management (yum install, or apt-get) . But if it is not possible then you may try the steps below.

If you have the so file (in your case imagick.so) which is fully functional (and virus free) in a server of EXACTLY the same linux distribution and version. You may try to copy the file to your target server path:

```
/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so
```

or, if the server is 32 bit

```
/usr/lib32/php/modules/imagick.so
```

then open your php.ini (mostly it is /etc/php.ini) and at the end of the file add the following:

```
extension=imagick.so
```

After that, restart your apache and it should be ok. However, please make sure you can access this server for further troubleshooting because in case of any problem you can revert the changes you have made.

Comment: Thank you. Your suggested steps worked like a charm.