# php repository is unavailable for Ubuntu-16.04 as per Dec 16, 2021. Need to add imap module

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, php-7.2

Ubuntu 16.04.06 with php7.0.33. I can only install php7.0-dev package.

Is it possible to compile php7.2.34-imap module using php7.0-dev package?
I downoladed php7.2.34 source, I'm in source/ext/imap/ directory and run

> phpize

will it give the right ./configure file to compile 7.2.34-imap?

The server is in progress to be updated to Ubuntu 20.04 but it will take time and development is delayed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a newbie. I have never ever compiled any php source.
It took me a couple of days of testing to successfully compile php module and transfer it to a production server.

1. When php source is compiled php-dev is created as part of compiled version. There is a good example how to. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102910/how-to-build-php-7-3
2. After compiling and installing php - compile a module. Good info is here: https://serverfault.com/questions/422010/add-module-to-custom-compiled-php
3. Transfer a module to another server: [Manual Installation of php extension (copy from one server to another)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65263093/manual-installation-of-php-extension-copy-from-one-server-to-another)